# Reputation not calculated correctly?

Tags: support, reputation

If you link your other SO accounts to this one, you start with 101 rep. I asked one question which was upvoted twice, but nevertheless i have only 106 rep. Why not 111?

Here is my reputation calc:

> total votes: 1
>   -- bonuses   (100)  2       197 (5)
>   -- 2011-01-29 rep +5    = 106
>
> ** total rep 106 :)
>
> days represented 0 rep cap was reached
>   via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
>   rep cap was exceeded on 0 days

Comment: Can you include a copy of the contents of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/reputation in your question?

Comment: @marcog Thanks, included it.

Comment: [User account](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/153/roflcoptr) and [question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197/freely-available-books-for-code-golfing) in question. I've asked about this on [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77100/how-does-a-se-site-in-beta-grab-the-attention-of-a-dev-when-support-tickets-bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second upvote on that post occured after the question was [turned into community wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/197/revisions), and upvotes on CW questions do not generate reputation.

Comment: Hod could I miss that. :P

Comment: me 2;) (.......)